# Networking Across Multiple Operating Systems

Tags: c++, networking, operating-system

I understand that Winsock is used for networking on Windows OS's, and BSD is for Mac OS and Unix. Is there some type of "universal" socket that works across any of the three operating systems mentioned? Or would a server have to have both sockets somehow incorporated into it for compatibility with clients of differing OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winsock and BSD Sockets are the names of two similar APIs that both implement the same thing: TCP/IP sockets, which in turn are endpoints of TCP connections or UDP datagram flows. Because the actual transport is defined by the TCP/IP RFCs, they interoperate. There is accordingly no necessity for a Winsock implementation on Unix, or a BSD Sockets implementation on Windows. Indeed the latter is what Winsock more or less is, modulo a few misunderstandings here and there.

In short, your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I did not know they were so similar, which was a sub-point of interest of my question.

Comment: @LucasS Their whole purpose is to be similar. I post here via an iPad or a Windows laptop: the server is probably a Solaris box running Java. That's the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are sockets, they just pump data. So you can have a server programmed in Java on Windows and a client programmed in C on BSD, and they will still be able to communicate with each other.

For cross-compiling without using 3rd party libraries, you can more-or-less easily do it by using some #ifdefs, see more @ http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html

Another way would be to use a 3rd party library, probably the easiest way and can bring other advantages into play, like more advanced functions, etc.
UDT comes to mind, but there are other. ( http://udt.sourceforge.net/ )

Comment: Only sockets which fulfil the POSIX standard are compartible over multiple OS. for example Berkley Sockets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets

Comment: Upvoted pointless unexplained incorrect downvote.

Comment: @JanKoester Nonsense. Sockets which purport to be TCP sockets are compatible over all RFC-compliant TCP implementations. TCP is not defined by POSIX. Java sockets for example are not POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little secret: Winsock is based on BSD sockets. Except for initializing and closing the winsock library, the actual networking code library is identical between BSD and Windows sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Winsock is BSD compatible if you avoid some of the more advanced functions. The trick is respecting endianess when dealing with non byte data. Floating points can get tricky depending on your architecture and language. Char arrays will keep things predictable, but that can be limiting. You only need the one server if the protocols are followed.